# How can I get the value of an Android EditText component as an integer?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am building an app that solves the quadratic formula based on the user inputs for A, B, and C. I have a problem. A, B, and C are all integers, but they need to take the values of an EditText component, editText1 (and 2, 3), so the formula has A, B, C to run.

How can I get the values? Here is my code where this part is missing:

```
    double root1=0;
    double root2=0;
    double discriminant;
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            //reset button will be a menu option

        final TextView textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        EditText inputA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
        EditText inputB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText inputC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3); 
        Button calcbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calcbutton); 


        calcbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // when calculate is clicked 

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                discriminant = Math.sqrt((B*B)-(4*A*C));

                if(discriminant>0){
                    root1 =  ((-B + discriminant)/2*A);
                    root2 =  ((-B - discriminant)/2*A);

                    // set textview6 to answer above    

                    textView6.setTag(root1 );
                    textView6.setTag(root2);
                    }

                if(discriminant==0){

                    root1=(int) ((-B + discriminant)/2*A);
                    textView6.setTag(root1);
                }

                if(discriminant<0){
                    textView6.setText("This equation has imaginary roots");
                    // equation has imaginary roots
                }


            }
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: Just one more note for your mathematics: The discriminant is the term below the root, i.e. `(B*B)-(4*A*C)`. You can't reasonably take the square root of a negative number, e.g. you should first check its sign and then take the root.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the API docs, you'll see that you can access the value in an `EditText` using [`EditText#getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29).

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    A = Double.parseDouble(inputA.getText().toString());
    B = Integer.parseInt(inputB.getText().toString());
    C = Integer.parseInt(inputC.getText().toString());

    discriminant = Math.sqrt((B*B)-(4*A*C));
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. I tried something like this but I did it wrong. This now makes more sense to me. Thank you! I appreciate this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `string` to an `int` or other types using the following:

```
 // convert text to an integer
int    number = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());

// convert text to a double
double number = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `EditText#getText()` returns an `Editable`, not a `String`.